# MySQL delete row until certain point

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building an auction site for a client and I have a problem where I need to remove bids from the bid table until a certain point, that point is determined by the number of bidders or a reserve price.

Let me explain further. I have a table with data:

```
Bidder1 $7,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
Bidder2 $7,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:26:34
Bidder1 $6,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
Bidder2 $6,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:26:11
Bidder1 $5,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
Bidder2 $5,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:34
Bidder2 $1,100.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:23:53
Bidder1 $1,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
Bidder1 $550.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
Bidder2 $500.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:23
Bidder2 $100.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:23
```

As you can see there are 2 bidders fighting it out. Now each bidder is able to cancel their bids at anytime however, say bidder2 cancels their bids, the system flags all bids on the auction as cancelled (client requirement) not just their latest one. If that is the case (bidder2 cancels their bids) then bidder1's bids should roll right back to $1000 which is the reserve price for the auction (as you should be able to tell because there are 2 bids in a row from bidder1, $550 and $1000).

Heres what I am hoping is just the tricky bit and not the impossible bit. Say I have 3 bidders:

```
Bidder1 $7,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
Bidder2 $7,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:26:34
Bidder3 $6,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
Bidder2 $6,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:26:11
Bidder1 $5,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
Bidder2 $5,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:34
Bidder3 $1,100.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:23:53
Bidder1 $1,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
Bidder1 $550.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
Bidder2 $500.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:23
Bidder2 $100.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:23
```

If bidder2 cancels their bids then I need to roll back until the latest bid of bidder3 but still with bidder1 winning.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what should the bid amount be for bidder1? still 7.25k or 6.25k+1? or?

Comment: you should generalize the logic for 3,4,...n users. As of now I can't see any thing common between first and second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first count total no. of bidders

```
$result = mysql_query("select distinct(bidder_id) from table where bid_id=1");
```

//consider we want to remove bidder_id=2 bids

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 2 ) {
 //select min bid of bidder
 $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select * from table where bidder_id=2 order by bid_price asc limit 1"));

 $bidder_min_amount = $row['bid_price'];
 $bidder_min_id = $row['id'];

 //find out other bidder min bid id 
    /*
    Bidder1 $7,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
    Bidder2 $7,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:26:34
    Bidder1 $6,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
    Bidder2 $6,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:26:11
    Bidder1 $5,250.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:44
    Bidder2 $5,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:25:34
    Bidder2 $1,100.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:23:53
    Bidder1 $1,000.00  Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
    Bidder1 $550.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
    Bidder2 $500.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:23
    Bidder2 $100.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:23
    //may be first case like this
    Bidder1 $75.00    Sat 21 Jul 2012 12:22:33
    */ 
    //finding out if Bidder1 $75.00 exist
    $row = mysql_query("select * from table where bid_price <= $bidder_min_amount and bidder_id!=2 order by bid_price asc");
    if(mysql_num_rows($row) > 0 ) { 
     mysql_query("delete from table where id > ".$row['id'] );
    } else {
      $row = mysql_query("select * from table where bid_price >= $bidder_min_amount and bidder_id!=2 order by bid_price asc");
      if(mysql_num_rows($row) > 0 ) { 
         mysql_query("delete from table where id > ".$row['id'] );
        }
    } 
} //first condition complete if total bidder is 2
else {
    //if n bidders just remove the bids of bidder
    mysql_query("delete from table where bidder_id=2");
}
```

Hope this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to handle two scenarios - the first is if the cancelling bidder is the highest bidder; the second is if the cancelling bidder is not the highest bidder.

If the cancelling bidder is the highest bidder, you can delete every bid after their first bid, including other users' bids. If they're not the highest bidder, you would just delete all of their bids and leave the other users alone. This is based on the sample-cases you provided; let me know if this is not correct and I'll adjust.

I'm assuming your db structure is more or less like this:

```
users
    id
    name
bids
    id
    user_id
    auction_id
    price
```

Before running your delete, I would grab the `MAX(id)` for the current auction and for the cancelling bidder's bid for the current auction (assume the auction is #1, cancelling bidder is #2):

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_auction FROM bids WHERE auction_id=1
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_bidder FROM bids WHERE auction_id=1 AND user_id=2
```

Then, you would compare both of those and process as needed:

```
if ($max_auction == $max_bidder) {
    // the cancelling-bidder is the highest-bidder
    // get the ID of their first bid so we can delete every bid after it
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(id) FROM bids WHERE auction_id=1 AND user_id=2");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM bids WHERE auction_id=1 AND id>=" . $row[0]);
} else {
    // the cancelling-bidder is not the highest-bidder
    // just remove all of their bids
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM bids WHERE auction_id=1 AND user_id=2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more than two bidders:

1. Group by bidder and max bid, will give you one row for each bidder and their max bid.
2. Delete exiting bidder's bids.
3. Order table by date entered, then bid, group by bidders.
4. Delete all rows where bid entered < lowest bid from the results of #3. This will remove all bids leading up to the lowest bid, now leaving one bid for each users which is their last bid.

You have a special case where there are only two bidders:

1. Delete exiting bidder's rows.
2. Search for rows where bid price = reserve price
3. If there are rows, delete all rows where bid price is < reserve price. This leaves you the last bid that matched the reserve price.
4. If there are no rows, which means the reserve was not met, delete all rows where bid < max(bid). This leaves one row which is the current max bid on the auction.

This is a bit verbose - you don't need to group by each time - but I wrote it so that you can confirm the results when you run the queries from the db shell.